# Fail to load a 4 column CSV file into OCTAVE - output is only first column, or 1 array per line

Tags: csv, octave

Trouble loading a csv file into OCTAVE.

**EDIT**: as pointed out from ANDY and Eliahu Aaron, I changed `;` to `,`.
csvread 4 returns separated columns, each named after the first line.

My matlab script throws these errors:

> error: 'z' undefined near line 13 column 3
>   error: called from myScript at line 13 column 2

I can0t find -z even though there is now a column called `z` from where it should calculate.

This fixed my Issue in the end:

```
g = cell2mat(A(2:end-1,2));
```

My csv looks like this:

```
time;z;y;x
5;15084;-1360;-9664
7;15280;-1296;-9784
10;15032;-1384;-9688
30;15160;-1548;-9772
56;15116;-1532;-9660
```

First I had to delete the first row- because matrix was unreadable for octave.

If I try to csv2cell  my file - I only get 1 column filled with all values in every line

```
mycsvdata = csv2cell("file.csv")
```

if I try csvread i get 1 column with the values of the first column name "ans"... 2nd,3rd and 4th column is ignored.

```
csvread("file.csv")
```

---

when i drag and drop the same csv into matlab - i click on the green tick and every column is named after its first cell and is a var. I end up having 4 vars called: time, z, y and x.
In octave this is kind of impossible for me to archieve.

what am i doing wrong?
This seems to be such a basic problem but I havent come across a solution in the internet.

---

I need to get 4 variables called time, z, y and x and having them all the values from the 1st (time), 2nd(z), 3rd(y) and 4th(x) column stored in them

I am new to octave and have a code written for matlab - which I want to change to octave. I am not even able to test my code, becuase I am not able to load the csv properly. This is very frustrating for me.

thanks in adavance

Comment: I you read the first two setences from `help csv2cell` you'll discover, that: "Read a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file and convert it into a cell array. SEP (a character value) changes the character used to separate two fields.  The default value is a comma (',').`

Comment: thanks for that Info. I changed my ; to , and the only problem remaining is the first row. instead of naming a variable after the first line - octave just turns it into a 0. I need a command to tell OCTAVE that the first line is ment to be name the var. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV by default uses `,` as column delimiters but your file has `;` as column delimiters.

You can use `dlmread("file.csv", ";")` instead of `csvread` but it can't read the first row `time;z;y;x`.

You can use `csv2cell("file.csv", ";")`, the first row will be strings and the rest numbers.

To create a struct array with fields `time;z;y;x` you can use the fullowing code:

```
pkg load io
A = csv2cell("file.csv", ";");
B = cell2struct(A(2:end,:),A(1,:),2);
```

Comment: what i understand is - that i should replace the ";" with "," in my csv. that is no problem. if I try to 

A = csv2cell(fileName, ";");

I get the error:

error: 'csv2cell' undefined near line 1 column 5

what might that be?
second line doesnt work anyway - because i havent defined A.

Anyway - if I replace my";" with"," and use the csv2cell i get what I want - having 4 seperated colums... the only thing is - the first line is 0,0,0,0 <-- how can I tell OCTAVE to name the columns after the first line? 
What I need is a "var" which is called time and z - and then script

Comment: Did you load `io` package? if no, just add the line `pkg load io`.

Comment: @eliahu: it's possible that he has installed Octave without the forge packages in which case he has to install io first

Comment: @Andy: He uses `csv2cell` which is part `io` package

Comment: yes... didnt load the io. sorry about that- yes the dates now looks like how i need them. When i run the matlab script - it says var (z) is still missing. but it is named? the 2nd column. or I am mixing up something?
error: 'z' undefined near line 13 column 3
error: called from myScript at line 13 column 2

Comment: @tno: z is a field in the struct B you need to use B.z

Comment: @EliahuAaron this works now. next errors i receive are due trying to run a matlab script. I will try to figure most errors out by myself- I will post within the next day again, if I have any troubles I cant solve by my self. Thanks very much

Comment: @EliahuAaron Please read my comment again... Your answer to it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @EliahuAaron sorry for being unclear. i tried B.z and it didnt work. After some trying around I found this works for me: g = cell2mat(A(2:end-1,2)); this stores all values from the 2nd colum (z) -1 (because the last information is allways a bit messa from my accelerometer) into a new var g. with that i cant run my script and everything works like in matlab.

Comment: @EliahuAaron everything I needed is solved by You. Thank you very much.
ah and befor i forget - i needed to install the package "signal" too, to work with my script (butterworthfilter)